# BOX name changing

Tags: boxes

I am unable to change the box name using flotrow.sty. Kindly advice

**Box 1 :**  should be changed to **BOX 1 :**

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\DeclareNewFloatType{Box}{%
  placement=htbp,%
  fileext=lob}%

\floatsetup[Box]{%
  style=BOXED,%
  capposition=top,%
  justification=justified}%



\newenvironment{BOX}[2][htbp]{%
  \begin{Box}[#1]%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\processtable{\textbf{#2}\vspace*{-6.5pt}}\fi%
}{\end{Box}}%

\newenvironment{BOX*}[2][htbp]{%
  \begin{Box*}[#1]%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{\textbf{#2}\vspace*{-6.5pt}}\fi%
}{\end{Box*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{BOX*}[!t]{Among  the various hydrocarbon polymers}
Among  the various hydrocarbon polymers, polyether ether ketone (PEEK) based membranes are well known ({Xing:2004}; {Jiang:2005}; {Fathima:2007}) due to their good thermal stability, appropriate mechanical strength, and when sulfonated, good proton conductivity, which increases with the degree of sulfonation (DS). However, these aromatic polymer electrolytes with high IEC, which show high proton conductivity, have the problem of weak mechanical behavior due to some water solubility, and this is one of the main obstacles for application in PEMFCs ({Dyck:2002}; {Roziere:2003}; {Karlsson:2005}; {Parcero:2006}; {DiVona:2010}).
\end{BOX*}

\end{document}
```

My Required output below mentioned

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the label is the same as the environment's name; just change it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\DeclareNewFloatType{Box}{
  name=BOX,
  placement=htbp,
  fileext=lob
}

\floatsetup[Box]{
  style=BOXED,
  capposition=top,
  justification=justified
}

\newenvironment{BOX}[2][htbp]{%
  \begin{Box}[#1]%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\processtable{\textbf{#2}\vspace*{-6.5pt}}\fi%
}{\end{Box}}%

\newenvironment{BOX*}[2][htbp]{%
  \begin{Box*}[#1]%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{\textbf{#2}\vspace*{-6.5pt}}\fi%
}{\end{Box*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{BOX*}[!t]{Among  the various hydrocarbon polymers}
Among  the various hydrocarbon polymers, polyether ether ketone (PEEK) based membranes are well known ({Xing:2004}; {Jiang:2005}; {Fathima:2007}) due to their good thermal stability, appropriate mechanical strength, and when sulfonated, good proton conductivity, which increases with the degree of sulfonation (DS). However, these aromatic polymer electrolytes with high IEC, which show high proton conductivity, have the problem of weak mechanical behavior due to some water solubility, and this is one of the main obstacles for application in PEMFCs ({Dyck:2002}; {Roziere:2003}; {Karlsson:2005}; {Parcero:2006}; {DiVona:2010}).
\end{BOX*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I Got the solution.